# How do I raise the DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX when user attempts to enter duplicate ID

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception, oracle11g

Yes, I ask numerous questions because I learn more here than from the books. I've created a simple code block that produces desired output but it seems to simple for the current learning block i'm in. Would this code work for anyone that attempts to update the iddonor for a donor table if the id already exists? Haven't learned procedures or functions yet but can guess that would be a more sensible method. Does what i have thus far satisfy and exception handler if a condition arises or should I add more in the declaration? Appreciate the suggestions and learning points if provided.

My Code:

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dd_donor (iddonor)
   VALUES (305)

EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID already Exists');
END;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is there a unique index/constraint or primary key constraint on the ID column? Why are you trapping the exception and then using dbms_output, which the client may not be configured to see? You mention update but only show insert, which is also a bit confusing.

Comment: First question is, do you have a supporting **unique index** on the column?

Comment: Yes the iddonor column is the Primary Key constraint. Apologies for not identifying that. This project is not for business end, I'm trying to learn many different languages. My desired goal is to create an exception handler if someone attempts to enter a duplicate id in the iddonor column. The code didn't seem complex enough that I posted and was asking the professionals to correct and teach if possible....Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX** exception is raised when you try to store **duplicate values** in a column that is supported by a **unique index**.

Let's see a simple example. I have created a table with single column and made it the primary key, which will be supported by an implicit unique index.

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(ID NUMBER);

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT t_uk PRIMARY KEY(ID);

Table altered.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(ID) VALUES(1);

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL> BEGIN
  2  INSERT INTO t(ID) VALUES(1);
  3  END;
  4  /
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (LALIT.T_UK) violated
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

So, the unique constraint is violated. Let's see how to capture **DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX** exception:

**Test case**

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> BEGIN
  2  INSERT INTO t(ID) VALUES(1);
  3  EXCEPTION
  4  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
  5    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Duplicate value on index');
  6  END;
  7  /
Duplicate value on index

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

By the way, the DBMS_OUTPUT was only for demo purpose, ideally you wouldn't have it in your production code.

Comment: the iddonor column is (PK with unique constraint). Appreciate the way you created the tables to show what is happening. Now I assume a procedure could be created in the future that executes on a larger scale DB for users that have privileges to update, insert...etc, No?

Comment: You could use the same logic for both insert and updates. Exception could be handled programmatically in PL/SQL. In pure SQL you would expect `unique constraint (schema.constraint_name) violated` error.